# Extract data from an existing file using Awk to a new file

Tags: awk, extract

Data Set in `us-500.txt` is set up like:

```
first_name last_name     email             web
john        Doe      info@gmail.com   www.info.com
```

Using AWK, how do I extract the first name, last name, email, and web from the `us-500.txt` to a new file that was created called `nomore.txt`

I have already tried

```
awk -F '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' us-500.txt
```

Comment: only `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' us-500.txt > nomore.txt`

Comment: Thanks!!! Your awesome

Answer (score 0):

only awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' us-500.txt > nomore.txt –  Jose Ricardo Bustos M.